# Find words with at most two vowels

Tags: r, regex

I have made a function to search words which have two vowels together. The function give me the vowels together (for example: ee, ou), but I need the complete word (tree, four).

```
lt <- c("tree", "four", "hello", "play")

vowel <- function(x) {  
  a<- regexpr(pattern = "[aeiou]{2}", x) 
    regmatches(x, a)
}

vowel(lt)

# [1] "ee" "ou"
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you looking to do a word similarity?

Comment: No, I am searching different patterns for then applying to Single Nucleotide Repeats (SNP). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply use `grepl` which in my opinion is more user friendly.

```
vowel <- function(x) 
   
 {  
   a<- grepl("[aeiou]{2}", x) 
   x[a]
 }
 vowel(lt)
[1] "tree" "four"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to replace

```
[aeiou]{2}
```

with

```
\w*[aeiou]{2}\w*
```

to include the letters before and after the double vowel in the word.

Comment: Nope, it matches words of any length containing two subsequent vowels. `\w*` matches any letter character zero or more times. Check https://regex101.com/r/cpEBth/1.

Comment: Yes, you are of course completely right. I don't know what caused my momentary blindness that made me see `\\b` where there was `\\w` ... apologies for the comment

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution with `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

lt[str_count(lt, '[^aeiou]') ==2]
```

```
[1] "tree" "four"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `regexpr` returns `-1` if there is no match.  Therefore, instead of using `regmatches`, the index itself can be used to subset if we convert to logical

```
lt[regexpr("[aeiou]{2}", lt) >0]
[1] "tree" "four"
```